iOS Keyboard not hiding on another view tap
I have a stack view with UITextField (textView) and UIView (dropdown) in it.
Its a backend-driven UI, therefore the views are not initialized on screen load. Rather theyre added after UI request is completed and setup looks like this:
func configureView(with models: [ElementType]) {
        models.forEach {
            switch $0.self {
            case .text(let model):
                let view = TextFloatView()
                view.delegate = self
                view.configure(with: model)
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
            case .dropdown(let model):
                let view = DropdownField()
                view.delegate = self
                view.configure(with: model)
                stackView.addArrangedSubview(view)
            case .unknown:
                break
            }
        }
    }

While editing textView, and touching anywhere on the screen, keyboard hides properly without a problem. However when i click dropdown, focus stays on the textView and keyboard doesn't hide.
Dropdown has an action, in which i've tried adding
stackView.arrangedSubviews
        .compactMap { $0 as? TextFloatView }
        .forEach { $0.textField.resignFirstResponder()
                    view.endEditing(true) }

Doesn't work though.
Please help me hide keyboard.


What's the type of the drop down? A pop up UIButton or something? You should also show a [mcve].

@Sweeper its a custom UIView with a UIButton on it, which helps to observe dropdown tapping.
Attached a screenshot

@Sweeper Ive added some more code for understanding, pls have a look

In your hiding keyboard code, do you find textfieldds, have you printed to see that ?
